# How do you get the largest number and smallest number in a For-Loop function, The problems asks for a 10 number input and count specific type numbers

Tags: c

Hey guys I'm trying to figure this problem which counts as specific type of numbers yet I cant seem to get the largest and smallest number as stated on the problem, p.s we are not allowed to use lists or what so ever that would make the code easier, we're on controlled structures and if statements atm. Here's the problem "Input 10 integers. Display the total count of positive, negative, odd numbers, even numbers, largest and smallest numbers"

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int numInput;
int count;
int result = 0;
int postiveNum = 0, negativeNum  = 0, oddNum  = 0, evenNum = 0, largestNum = 0, smallestNum = 0;
printf("Please input a number: \n");
for(count = 1; count <= 10; count++)
{
scanf("%d", &numInput);
if (postiveNum >= postiveNum)
{
    largestNum = postiveNum;
}
if(postiveNum <= postiveNum)
{
    smallestNum = postiveNum;
}
if(numInput > 0)
{
postiveNum++;
}
 if(numInput < 0)
{
negativeNum++;
}
 if(numInput % 2 != 0)
{
    oddNum++;
}
 if(numInput % 2 == 0)
{
    evenNum++;
}
};

printf("Positive Numbers: %d\n", postiveNum);
printf("Negative Numbers: %d\n", negativeNum);
printf("Odd Numbers: %d\n", oddNum);
printf("Even Numbers: %d\n", evenNum);
printf("Largest Number: %d\n", largestNum);
printf("Smallest Number: %d\n", smallestNum);

}
```

Comment: `postiveNum <= postiveNum` is a tautology (i.e. always true)... And you don't compare `numInput` at all. Didn't you mean `if(input <= smallest) { smallest = input; }` – though I'd rather check for `<` to avoid overwriting `smallest` with exactly the same value...

Comment: Apart from those incorrect comparisons, initialise with `int largestNum = INT_MIN, smallestNum = INT_MAX;` and `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: Side note: Your odd/even checks are complementary, if something is unequal, it cannot be equal and if it is not unequal, it must be equal. So you should omit the second check and have an `else` instead...

Comment: Alternatively to @WeatherVane 's proposition you might instead read the very first value directly into `largest` and assign that to `smallest` as well, spares two comparisons...

Comment: You might want to move the prompt to enter a number into the loop so that the user is asked for *every* number.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numInput;
    int count;
    // initialize largest and lowest num with NULL
    int positiveNum = 0, negativeNum = 0, oddNum = 0, evenNum = 0, largestNum = NULL, smallestNum = NULL;

    // get 10 numbers as input
    for (count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {
        printf("Please input a number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &numInput);

        // if its the first iteration, initialize largest and lowest num with first input value
        // then compare the values from next iteration onwards
        if (count == 1) {
            smallestNum = numInput;
            largestNum = numInput;
        } else {
            // if input num is less than smallest num, rewrite the value
            if (numInput < smallestNum)
                smallestNum = numInput;

            // if input num is greater than the largest num, rewrite the value
            if (numInput > largestNum)
                largestNum = numInput;
        }

        // a number can't be positive and negative at the same time so use if else
        if (numInput < 0)
            negativeNum++;
        else
            positiveNum++;

        // a number can't be even and odd at the same time so use if else
        if (numInput % 2 == 0)
            evenNum++;
        else
            oddNum++;
    };

    printf("Positive Numbers: %d\n", positiveNum);
    printf("Negative Numbers: %d\n", negativeNum);
    printf("Odd Numbers: %d\n", oddNum);
    printf("Even Numbers: %d\n", evenNum);
    printf("Largest Number: %d\n", largestNum);
    printf("Smallest Number: %d\n", smallestNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare different variables in the if statement, change

```
if (postiveNum >= postiveNum){
    largestNum = postiveNum;
```

for

```
if (numInput > largestNum){ 
// you should compare to the variable you want to change inside the if statement
    largestNum = numInput;
}
```

the same for the smallest

```
if (numInput < smallestNum){
    smallestNum = numInput;
}
```

Also the `largestNum` should be initialized as the minimum posible.
The same goes for `smallestNum`, but with the maximum posible.
This considering that the user could input just negative numbers and none of them will be `> 0` and your program will print 0 as the minimum number, even tho you never input that number.

Answer (score -1):

**Way to find the largest number amongst given input number**

I assume there's an input range.

Initialize the variable `largestNum` with the min number of that range.

Then for each input compare `largestNum` with that input and update the value of `largestNum` accordingly.

**Way to find the smallest number amongst given input number**

Apply the same procedure for finding the smallest number.

The difference is, here you've to initialize the variable `smallestNum` with the max number of the input range.

**Note**: I've considered max input range as `-10^6 >= input <= 10^6`. Change it according to your problem requirement.

Here's a possible sample code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MIN_NUMBER -1000000
#define MAX_NUMBER 1000000
int main()
{
    int numInput;
    int count;
    int result = 0;
    int postiveNum = 0, negativeNum  = 0, oddNum  = 0, evenNum = 0, largestNum = MIN_NUMBER, smallestNum = MAX_NUMBER;

    for(count = 1; count <= 10; count++)
    {
        printf("Please input a number: \n");    // print it before taking every input
        scanf("%d", &numInput);

        if (numInput > largestNum)
        {
            largestNum = numInput;
        }
        if(numInput < smallestNum)
        {
            smallestNum = numInput;
        }
        if(numInput > 0)
        {
            postiveNum++;
        }
        if(numInput < 0)
        {
            negativeNum++;
        }
        if(numInput % 2 != 0)
        {
            oddNum++;
        }
        if(numInput % 2 == 0)
        {
            evenNum++;
        }
    }

    printf("Positive Numbers: %d\n", postiveNum);
    printf("Negative Numbers: %d\n", negativeNum);
    printf("Odd Numbers: %d\n", oddNum);
    printf("Even Numbers: %d\n", evenNum);
    printf("Largest Number: %d\n", largestNum);
    printf("Smallest Number: %d\n", smallestNum);
}
```